# How to change configuration properties of Ext Js components after they are rendered

Tags: javascript, extjs

There are scenarios when I have to change some configuration properties of Ext Js components after render. In Api documentation, I don't see getters/setters for most of the configs. Is there any way to change configuration and then re-render component or Update layout?

In the following code I need to change collapsible property to true or false dynamically after the Ext.form.FieldSet is rendered:

```
 var container = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     layout: {
         type: "vbox"
     }
 });

 var fieldset = Ext.create("Ext.form.FieldSet", {
     renderTo: "fieldset"
 });

 var text = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text", {
     renderTo: "text"
 });

 var button = Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
     renderTo: "button",
     text: "My Button"
 });

 fieldset.add(text);
 fieldset.add(button);

 container.add(fieldset);
```

Also the below code does not update layout:

```
 Ext.apply(fieldset,{collapsible:true,style:"bakground:red"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2nyhE/

Answer (score 0):

```
fld.titleCmp.el.on({
    'click': fld.toggle,
    scope: fld
});

fld.titleCmp.el.addCls(me.baseCls + '-header-text-collapsible');

fld.legend.items.add(fld.createToggleCmp());
fld.legend.updateLayout();
```

http://jsbin.com/IFUZut/1/

Comment: Nice try, but It keeps on adding collapse button to the container if I click "Add Collapse" button multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

there is methods [collapse](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet-method-collapse) and [expand](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet-method-expand) which you could call on your field set to collapse or expand it.

You can try this. Set an id property for the desired fieldset `(id:'anyId')` and use `Ext.apply(Ext.getCmp('anyId'), {your config object});`

`Ext.applay` [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-apply)

You can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098596/how-to-adding-fields-config-on-the-fly)

And also you can read about what is the difference between `Ext.apply` and simple javascript parameter adding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268422/what-is-the-point-of-ext-apply-versus-simply-setting-values-on-the-target/5277616#5277616).

Comment: Does it work even if collapsible property is set to false in configuration? Furthermore, my question is not specific to collapsible property. I need a generic way to set config properties after they are rendered.

Comment: I wrote the following code but the layout is not updated: Ext.apply(fieldset,{collapsible:true, style: "background:red"}); Also tried doLayout and updateLayout after but no affect.

Comment: you should add `id` property to your field set, and call `Ext.getCmp('yourID')` in the `Ext.applay` function

Comment: The fieldset variable used already contains the component object. See the last line of my code.

Comment: try `Ext.getCmp('anyId').collapsible = true`. This one is my last suggestion, i don't have any other possible solutions